# Shading not working in Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, 3dsmax, revit

I´m having problems with normals in blender and can´t find anything about this specific problem on the internet. I have made a building in Revit and exported it as FBX to Blender. In the end I want to use it in Unity. As I imported the FBX in Blender all the walls had strange edges and the normals would look like this (smooth shading on):

[import to blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxdDP.png)

So I used the decimate modifier to remove these unnecessary edges. The result was this:

[decimate applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6G0D.png)

It looks like the normals are fine, but the shading looks very strange. 
After importing the model to Unity, the shadows remain. Even when I first export it as an FBX file. I tried recalculating the normals with no result. I tried to export it via 3ds Max, but it didn't make any difference. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the UV coordinates (inc. lightmap UVs) are no longer correct.  I haven't used blender with Unity, so I'm unsure on what the decimate command actually does to a model.  That said, Unity is pretty good at rendering complex models (there's more overhead on separate meshes than more vertices) so the command is probably not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed all blender materials in Unity and added new ones. Now the shadows are gone. But some walls aren´t reflecting light.